# Print the line in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to print one Line on PDF page. I try to set absolute coordinates for this, but my page is empty :

```
Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);
using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "Report.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{ 
    string ttf = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Futuris Cyrillic.TTF");
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ttf, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

    doc.Open();
    doc.NewPage();
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("", font));
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    LowHatPrint(cb, 1);

    doc.Close();
}

//.......

private void LowHatPrint(PdfContentByte cb, int number)
{
    cb.SetLineWidth(4);
    cb.SetGrayStroke(1);
    cb.MoveTo(0, 0);
    cb.LineTo( 100,  100);
    cb.Stroke();
}
```

What is the problem with `LowHatPrint` ?

Comment: wheres the text you're writing on the page?

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103404/problem-in-drawing-a-line-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp

Comment: @YairHalberstadt in this moment need only Line

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I think it is literally a "line" , not a "line of text".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem in drawing a line in a pdf file using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103404/problem-in-drawing-a-line-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp)

Comment: @Fildor you are right. this is really not a "line of text"

Comment: @Fildor. thanks for reference!          
I needed rewrite only :
`cb.SetColorStroke(new BaseColor(255,0,0));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set Color of the line like

```
cb.SetColorStroke(new BaseColor(255,0,0));
```

Comment: thanks! perhaps, you can help in one more question. how to set width of line now?

Comment: Try `cb.SetLineWidth(4.0f);`